# Passing two parameters from txt file to object using Scanner.next() twice. Result: "Unknown Source"

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I have a text file containing some data, separated by white-space.

I have a constructor that accepts two types of data:

```
constructor(short members, int income){
    this.members = members;
    this.income = income;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to, in one swoop, pass the first number as a short, and the second number as an int, to one object.

My text file resembles this:

```
1 22229
2 27674
3 34022
4 41307
5 46850
6 52838
7 58827
```

My code resembles this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner fileScan;

        fileScan = new Scanner (new File("survey.txt"));


        List<Household> houseList = new ArrayList<Household>();

        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(fileScan.nextLine());

            /*
            houseList.add(new Household((short) fileScan.nextInt(),
                    fileScan.nextInt()));
            */
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < houseList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(houseList.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

I want it to work in such a way that

```
this.members = 1;
this.income = 2324;
```

If I pass either item to the object individually it runs, but when using nextInt() twice there is an error of "Unknown Source".

If there is a way to make this work, or a work-around to get this effect, I would much appreciate your help.

Thank you, and sorry if this question has already been answered.

Comment: Check what you are getting after you read a line in (use a debugger if you can, or print statements).  I suspect this will get you pointed in the right direction. Your first read of the file will give you "1 2324", but I think you're expecting "1".

Comment: @user Do you instantiate scanner with default parameters ? Could you verify your file only contains lines with TWO integers (or empty lines) ?

Comment: Yes, what I want to do is pass the '1', then pass the '2324'.
That was my logic for using fileScan.nextInt() twice when creating the new object.
Since it doesn't like the .next() being called more than once, the best way would be to get the .nextLine(), then separate it into two variables, and pass it to the object from those?
@kiruwka The file contains multiple lines, each with two integers. I will add my scanner instantiation to my code in OP.

Comment: HasNext is going to give you the whole line.  You'll need to come up with some other approach.  Separate the values on one line with a comma (or split on the space, but that always makes me nervous) and split them, something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] temp = fileScan.nextLine().split(" ");
        if (temp.length == 2){
            houseList.add(new Household(Short.parseShort(temp[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(temp[1])));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!
This works just how I wanted it... Just couldn't quite get my head around it alone.
The prompt assistance is greatly appreciated! 
Ty All!

Comment: As an alternative solution, after trying this, I simply organized my .txt file differently (separated with new lines, rather than new-lines and white-space), and used the nextInt(), etc, methods.